# Cron only runs part of bash script

Tags: bash, cron

I have a script that has to be run in a school server so I don't have root permissions and this script works perfectly when i run it manually.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d ~/public_html ] ; then 
  mkdir ~/public_html
fi
{
nicknameUsers=$(cat ouvintes.txt | cut -d ':' -f1)

echo "<html>"
echo -e "  <body>"

for user in $nicknameUsers; do 
  echo -e "    <h1>Nickname: $user</h1>"
  n=$(cat ouvintes.txt | grep "$user" | awk -F ':' '{print NF}' )
  #MORE CODE IN THE MIDDLE
done
echo -e "  </body>"
echo -e "</html>"
} > ~/public_html/stats.html
```

The problem is when it is runned by cron it only executes the first if and the echos that are outside of the for.

**Crontab:**

`25 15  * * * /home/a87566/projeto/publica_playlists.sh`

Is there anything I can do that does't require root permissions to make cron run the entirity of the script?

Comment: Sounds like your cat ouvintes.txt isn't returning anything

Comment: Where is ouvintes.txt? You probably need to specify the full path to it.

Comment: @GordonDavisson it's in the same directory as the script

Comment: @MiguelH File references in scripts aren't resolved relative to the script, but to whatever their working directory is. Normally, that's just inherited from the process that launched the script. `crond` runs things with the working directory set to your home directory. If you want the script to refer to files in the same directory it's in, you need to either supply the full path, or [have the script try to figure it out dynamically](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).